# Inverse trigonometric question

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x\sin\alpha}{1-x\cos\alpha})-tan^{-1}(\frac{x-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha})$ is independent of $x$ and is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$

Please guide how to proceed in this question...

Comment: Something's fishy here: substitute $\,x=0\,$ in the arctangents expression and you get zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio, the '-' minus sign in between is missing

Comment: How can you tell, lab? The OP hasn't even addressed my comment...

Answer (score 2):

The '-' sign is missing

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sin\alpha}{1-x\cos\alpha}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)$$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{x\sin\alpha}{1-x\cos\alpha}-\frac{x-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}}{1+\frac{x\sin\alpha}{1-x\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{x-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}}\right)$$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha)-(x-\cos\alpha)(1-x\cos\alpha)}{(1-x\cos\alpha)\sin\alpha+x\sin\alpha(x-\cos\alpha)}\right)  $$ assuming  $(1-x\cos\alpha)\sin\alpha\ne0$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x(\sin^2\alpha-1-\cos^2\alpha)+x^2\cos\alpha+\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha(1-2x\cos\alpha+x^2)}\right)$$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\alpha(1-2x\cos\alpha+x^2)}{\sin\alpha(1-2x\cos\alpha+x^2)}\right)\text{ using } \sin^2\alpha-1=-\cos^2\alpha$$

$$=\tan^{-1}(\cot\alpha)$$ assuming $1-2x\cos\alpha+x^2\ne0$

$$=\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\alpha\right)\right)=\frac\pi2-\alpha$$